# How good is the ability of Aspose Slides to create PPTX files with templating?

Tags: c#, templating, aspose-slides

I am trying to use Aspose Slides to generate a presentation using a template PPTX with a master slide and some layout slides that contain placeholders.
I want to make the slides conform to different themes that the user will select.

I use a code similar to this one:
http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/permalink/467028/466709/showthread.aspx#466709
..and the shapes seem to go to the position of the placeholder.

However some fonts and most (if not all) of the background and border colors are not being copied from the placeholder. For example, all the Rectangles that I add, have a blue background and border and not what I use on the placeholder.
What I am suspecting is that the Aspose people set those styles to the Rectangle as initial values, so the shape doesn't pick them from the placeholder.

I have asked this question in the Aspose Forum, but it takes them centuries to respond.
Has anyone done anything similar with success?
Am I the first that uses Aspose Slides for templating?!?!
There doesn't seem to be much info on the web about this stuff.
There's only some info on text placeholders but I don't deal with text only here (I have charts, tables and titles)...

And I don't think I can handle efficiently even titles with normal text placeholders...

**EDIT:**

What I get when I insert a new Rectangle in my PPTX, is a Rectangle (thank God!) that has a  border and a background EXACTLY similar to the one in the demo here:
http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/slidesnet/Creating+a+TextBox+on+SlideEx

That's why I suspect that Aspose is responsible for this problem. When you set a property for a shape it doesn't use the value from the placeholder. I don't think these blue colors are PowerPoint's default colors...

I have tried setting these values to `NotDefined` like so:

```
lAshp.FillFormat.FillType = FillTypeEx.NotDefined;
lAshp.FillFormat.SolidFillColor.ColorType = ColorTypeEx.NotDefined;
lAshp.LineFormat.FillFormat.FillType = FillTypeEx.NotDefined;
lAshp.LineFormat.FillFormat.SolidFillColor.ColorType = ColorTypeEx.NotDefined;
```

..and nothing changes.

Comment: I'm developer evangelist at Aspose and I have followed up your queries posted in our forums. As I can see, our support team is already in contact with you and trying to help resolve your issues. I hope, those issues will be sorted out soon. Please note that some issues might take a little more time due to the complexity involved, but rest assured, we'll try our best to help you the earliest possible. If you still find any problem, please do let us know, so we could escalate your issues. Looking forward to help you.

Comment: Thanks. I hope you solve these issues soon. I in a little hurry in a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Aspose forum topic:

http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/468796/textbox-title-not-picking-up-the-placeholder-s-style/showthread.aspx

Any news will be posted there (I guess).

Cheers!